# Calculate number of operations

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a Java program where I implement sorting algorithm. I need to calculate how many operations(or sentences I guess) were done during the execution. Is there any built method in JAVA API to do that?

Comment: Define "operation". By "sentence", did you mean Java "statement"? But no, there is no builtin way to do that.

Comment: Yes, the `+` operator does that. Use it to increase a counter for each operation.

Comment: But wouln't it make a big impact in algorithm execution time if each time I add 1 to counter?

Comment: @RadLexus How do you increase a `+` operator? You can increase a numeric *variable* using `++`, but how do you increase an *operator*? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add a counter to your comparator.  This should add less than 1 nano-second and it will be trivial compare to anything else you are doing.

> What do you mean by saying comparator? I do not use any

In that case, I suggest you add one which sorts and also counts the number of times it is called.

Comment: What do you mean by saying comparator? I do not use any.

Comment: By saying counter, do you mean int k = 0 and then k++ ?

Comment: @motleycrue There are other options, but that seems the simplest to me.

Comment: But still I would need to add k++ after each statement in that sorting algorithm. Am I right?

Comment: @motleycrue I would add it once each time the comparison is called if you want to count the number of comparisons. If you want to count the number of statements run, you would add it before each statement.

Comment: I tried this. Without adding k++ sorting takes 32seconds. After adding k++ it takes 62seconds.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to make a function that takes N as an argument and calculates how many statements should be executed?

Comment: I mean make that function by analysing sorting method on a paper.